# What is monitor parameter in python scapy?

Tags: python

```
from scapy.all import *
print(sniff(monitor=True))
```

What is monitor parameter in scapy and why my wifi adapter get disconnected every time i run the script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `monitor` argument uses tells your WiFi card to use [monitor mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode). In monitor mode, your WiFi card receives all wireless packets, not just the ones it is supposed to receive. This is very useful for sniffing.

A consequence of this is that if you're receiving all packets, then you don't know which packets are for you. Because of this, you essentially loose internet access from that card until monitor mode is turned off (which is when scapy exits).

So, your WiFi card isn't actually disconnecting, it is switching to monitor mode. However the effects are the same. The only solution is to have two network interfaces (one for scapy and one for internet access). This can be done with another WiFi card or an ethernet connection.

Comment: when i enable the monitor mode and start sniffing packets how can i choose a specific target ? and when i enable the monitor mode will scapy sniff packets also from my wifi adapter ?

Comment: @Tarek To sniff for a specific target, you have to filter out packets by MAC address (or IP address if you've decrypted the 802.11 frames). I'm not sure how to do this with scapy, but I'm sure there's documentation on it.

Comment: And yes, scapy will sniff packets from everything in monitor mode. However, your OS might prevent you from sending packets while in monitor mode.

Comment: so in scapy whenever i enable the monitor mode i won't be able to send my own packets just sniffing ?

Comment: and there is only the iface function and filter functions which are not for specifying a mac address or ip address how do i know how to sniff from a specific ip or mac address